# Code is partly grey in VScode, does anyone know why?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Even though my language is set to HTML, the code after my CSS style element is all grey. This is not because of syntax highlighting because the code above it is highlighted correctly. Are there any solutions that do not require me to go into the `settings.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At the bottom right on band blue there is information about the language used (here it is "svelte").
   [image: vsc]

Il you press it a popup with differents langages will appear so you can choise your langage. You will find more informations [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview)

2. Maybe an extention of your file is wrong
3. You can change color of your template in Code -> preferences -> color theme

Comment: Thanks! I'd already tried this, but I'd figured out the problem was that it was all after my style tag in the head, I just linked it all into a separate file and it's fine now.